# Changing the style of the xforms-xsltforms controls

Tags: css, xforms, xsltforms

Anyone known how to change the css of the controls on XSLTForms of [AgenceXml](http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms.htm)? I'm trying by changing the xsltforms.css but the changes doesn't seem to apply. Also tryed to style controls by specifying a style and class attrs, but it had no effect.

```
<xf:input ref="name" incremental="true"  class="form-control" style="color:red;">
    <xf:label>Name</xf:label>
    <xf:hint appearance="minimal">E.g. Marie</xf:hint>
</xf:input>
```

So, what should the right way?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: im not familuar with xforms but are you editing the `form-control` class in the .css file ?

Comment: Yeap Pogrindis, the form-control tag is defined by the bootstrap css file. So I wanna "connect" the style of the xforms with the style of bootstrap

Comment: is there any kind of re-init recompile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to know how to modify XSLTForms CSS stylesheet, or add your own styles, is to use a browser debugger and look at corresponding HTML tags.

--Alain

Comment: I already did it. The problem is no stylesheet declared in the html is really imported. You have to modify directly the css of their source code, and that make it impossible to allow the end user to add stylesheet

Comment: Did you try with <?css-conversion no?> ?

Comment: Hi Alain! I tryed writting <?css-conversion no?> in the top of the document and then with these lines, but didn't work:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<style type="text/css" src="style.css"> </style>

And I put some css code in the file (I know it works) inside CDATA tag but it's not working...

Comment: Neither the inline styling works. Eg: 
<xf:input ref="classname" incremental="true" style="width:97%">
</xf:input>

Comment: And if I use the config file, I put this and neither works... 

<extensions>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="xsltforms/less/ext-bootstrap.less"/>
<script src="xsltforms/less/less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</extensions>

What is the root file path I must specify? I really don't understand what to declare here

Comment: Done! :) I found your article, Alain! http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XRX/XSLTForms_and_eXist#Modifying_your_CSS_to_work_with_XSLTForms